# SAS: how to properly use intck() in proc sql

Tags: sql, sas

I have the following codes in SAS:

`proc sql;
create table play2
as select a.anndats,a.amaskcd,count(b.amaskcd) as experience
from test1 as a, test1 as b
where a.amaskcd = b.amaskcd and intck('day', b.anndats, a.anndats)>0
group by a.amaskcd, a.ANNDATS;
quit;`

The data test1 has 32 distinct obs, while this play2 only returns 22 obs. All I want to do is for each obs, count the number of appearance for the same amaskcd in history. What is the best way to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this would return 22 observations - which might not actually be 22 distinct from the 32 - is that this is a comma join, which in this case ends up being basically an inner join.  For any given row `a` if there are no rows `b` which have a later `anndats` with the same `amaskcd`, then that `a` will not be returned.

What you want to do here is a left join, which returns all rows from `a` once.

```
create table play2
  as select ...
  from test1 a
  left join test1 b
  on a.amaskcd=b.amaskcd
  where intck(...)>0
  group by ...
;
```

I would actually write this differently, as I'm not sure the above will do exactly what you want.

```
create table play2
  as select a.anndats, a.amaskcd,
    (select count(1) from test1 b
       where b.amaskcd=a.amaskcd
       and b.anndats>a.anndats  /* intck('day') is pointless, dates are stored as integer days */
    ) as experience
    from test1 a
    ;
```

If your test1 isn't already grouped by amaskcd and anndats, you may need to rework this some.  This kind of subquery is easier to write and more accurately reflects what you're trying to do, I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

If both the anndats variables in each dataset are date type (not date time) then you can simple do an equals.  Date variables in SAS are simply integers where 1 represents one day.  You would not need to use the intck function to tell the days differnce, just use subtraction.

The second thing I noticed is your code looks for > 0 days returned.  The intck function can return a negative value if the second value is less than the first.

I am still not sure I understand what your looking to produce in the query.  It's joining two datasets using the amaskcd field as the key.  Your then filtering based on anndats, only selecting records where b anndats value is less than a anndats or b.anndats < a.anndats.